# Cannot resolve method setText() in imageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm trying to do a simple project with Recyclerview and Cardview in Android Studio following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oq_xGMN0mRE).
But I'm getting an error in `onBindViewHolder` function line 32 saying it can't resolve the method `setText()` in `imageView` and I don't know why since `mTitle` is not an `ImageView` and it is a `TextView`:

```
package com.example.demoproject;


import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {
    Context c;
    ArrayList<Model> models; // this array list creates a list of arrays which parameters define in my model class

    public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Model> models) {
        this.c = c;
        this.models = models;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,null); // this line inflate my row
        return new MyHolder(view); // this will return my view to holder class
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, int i) {
        myHolder.mTitle.setText(models.get(i).getTitle()); // here i is position

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

MyHolder.java :

```
package com.example.demoproject.

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView mImaeView, mTitle;
    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.mImaeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageIv);
        this.mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can You add `MyHolder` class?

Comment: Sure.Already added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mTile` is not a `TextView` it is a `ImageView`. Change it to this:

```java
ImageView mImaeView; 
TextView mTitle;
```

And make sure that `itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);` returns `TextView`. Check in Your xml file (recycler view item) that You made it eveything well and `titleTv` is a `TextView`

Answer (score 1):

because setText() method is set on textview not in imageView